# ModuleDependencyException: Module Magnolia Standard Templating Kit (version 1.4.4) is dependent on dms version 1.5/*, which was not found

Tags: tomcat, magnolia

In eclipse, I have created a maven project "magnolia-empty-webapp" and I would like to use `magnolia STK`. I add `magnolia STK dependency` as follow:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-standard-templating-kit</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
```

After that I installed the project sucessfully (`right mousclick on the project ->run as -> maven install`)

Now When I run the project with the apache tomcat Server, I get the following error:

```
    Apr 30, 2014 2:44:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\work\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;C:\msysgit\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\work\filevault\vault-cli-2.3.6\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;.
Apr 30, 2014 2:44:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:magnolia-empty-webapp' did not find a matching property.
Apr 30, 2014 2:44:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 30, 2014 2:44:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 30, 2014 2:44:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 643 ms
Apr 30, 2014 2:44:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 30, 2014 2:44:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Apr 30, 2014 2:44:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanWebXml
WARNING: Failed to process TLD with path [cmsfn-taglib] and URI [/WEB-INF/cmsfn-taglib.tld]
java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanWebXml(TldConfig.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:569)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 26 more

Apr 30, 2014 2:44:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanWebXml
WARNING: Failed to process TLD with path [cms-util-taglib] and URI [/WEB-INF/cms-util-taglib.tld]
java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanWebXml(TldConfig.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:569)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 26 more

Apr 30, 2014 2:44:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanWebXml
WARNING: Failed to process TLD with path [cms-taglib] and URI [/WEB-INF/cms-taglib.tld]
java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanWebXml(TldConfig.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:569)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 26 more

Apr 30, 2014 2:44:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class info.magnolia.cms.servlets.MgnlServletContextListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: info.magnolia.module.model.reader.ModuleDependencyException: Module Magnolia Standard Templating Kit (version 1.4.4) is dependent on dms version 1.5/*, which was not found.
    at info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.PropertiesInitializer.loadAllModuleProperties(PropertiesInitializer.java:153)
    at info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.PropertiesInitializer.loadAllProperties(PropertiesInitializer.java:119)
    at info.magnolia.cms.servlets.MgnlServletContextListener.contextInitialized(MgnlServletContextListener.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: info.magnolia.module.model.reader.ModuleDependencyException: Module Magnolia Standard Templating Kit (version 1.4.4) is dependent on dms version 1.5/*, which was not found.
    at info.magnolia.module.model.reader.DependencyCheckerImpl.checkSpecificDependency(DependencyCheckerImpl.java:75)
    at info.magnolia.module.model.reader.DependencyCheckerImpl.checkDependencies(DependencyCheckerImpl.java:58)
    at info.magnolia.module.ModuleManagerImpl.loadDefinitions(ModuleManagerImpl.java:140)
    at info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.PropertiesInitializer.loadAllModuleProperties(PropertiesInitializer.java:148)
    ... 12 more
```

this is my complett pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>magnolia-project</artifactId>
    <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>magnolia-empty-webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>magnolia-empty-webapp</name>
  <description>The basic Magnolia webapp on which projects can depend.</description>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>with-optional-modules</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
          <artifactId>magnolia-module-workflow</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
          <artifactId>magnolia-module-samples</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
            <artifactId>magnolia-demo-project</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
            <artifactId>magnolia-module-dms</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-module-templating</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-module-admininterface</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-taglib-utility</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-taglib-cms</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-module-cache</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-module-exchange-simple</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-gui</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-jaas</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-module-fckeditor</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-module-mail</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-module-store-client</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackrabbit-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
      <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.openutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>openutils-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-standard-templating-kit</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
<!--    <dependency> -->
<!--        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId> -->
<!--        <artifactId>magnolia-module-dms</artifactId> -->
<!--        <version>1.5.2</version> -->
<!--    </dependency> -->
<!--    <dependency> -->
<!--        <groupId>info.magnolia.themes.blue</groupId> -->
<!--        <artifactId>magnolia-theme-blue</artifactId> -->
<!--        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
<!--    </dependency> -->

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <!-- these are the resources copied by the remote-resources-plugin -->
        <directory>${basedir}/target/maven-shared-archive-resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/cache</directory>
            </fileset>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/logs</directory>
            </fileset>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/repositories</directory>
            </fileset>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/templates</directory>
            </fileset>
            <fileset>
              <directory>src/main/webapp/tmp</directory>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <!-- these are the resources copied by the remote-resources-plugin -->
              <directory>${basedir}/target/maven-shared-archive-resources</directory>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.sf.alchim</groupId>
        <artifactId>winstone-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>embed</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>


        <repository>
          <id>magnolia.nexus.public</id>
          <url>http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>magnolia</id>
            <url>http://repo.magnolia-cms.com/m2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you comment out dependency to DMS? STK needs DMS to function properly and that's exactly what the error message says. By uncommenting

```
<!--    <dependency> -->
<!--        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId> -->
<!--        <artifactId>magnolia-module-dms</artifactId> -->
<!--        <version>1.5.2</version> -->
<!--    </dependency> -->
```

you should be able to get rid of that error. IIRC there's bunch of other modules it will need.

Alternative to the above is to configure eclipse to run build with *with-optional-modules* profile, but then you get also demo modules which is probably not what you want.

For complete list of dependencies, you can look inside of the module jar file at /META-INF/magnolia/standard-templating-kit.xml. This file contains list of runtime dependencies. Or you can look at pom of the stk-bundle to see what other modules it includes when creating bundle.

HTH,
Jan